# How to apply the button's action to a text filed if the user pressed the button before returning the keyboard the keyboard

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield

I'm doing a simple calculator that does a multiplication for the number that the user entered when he touch the button . its working fine but  if the user pressed the button before he presses done on the key board , the calculator wont work because the user didnt press done so no value is stored . So how can I make sure that the value is stored if the user presses the button before he presses done .

[image]

the code for the m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString* number;
@property (nonatomic) double ans;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.number= self.enteredValue.text;
    if (textField == self.enteredValue) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        self.ans = [self.enteredValue.text doubleValue];
        self.answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.ans];
    }
    NSLog(@"%f",self.ans);
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)multiplierPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.ans*10];
}

@end
```

the header file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *enteredValue;

- (IBAction)multiplierPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answer;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already identified the cause of your problem: you only save the value when the user taps Done and use that value. How can you solve that? Well, you could save the value anytime the user types something. When loading your view controller, add a new action for the text change event:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This will make the textFieldDidChange: method be called when the text in the text field changes.

Alternatively you could stop saving the value into your own instance variable, and just use the value that is currently in the text field, when the user taps the x10 button.

```
- (IBAction)multiplierPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    float enteredValue = [self.textField.text floatValue];
    self.answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", enteredValue * 10];
}
```

In this case, you'll have to declare a textField property in your view controller and assign it in Interface Builder.

Comment: the 1st solution is making the program crash when I enter a number.

Comment: the 2nd solutions worked :) but when the user then presses return , it gives the answer to be the same as the number he entered :( and I cant just make the keyboard disappear when the button is pressed . because in my app the button will have 3 multipliers so if I made the keyboard disappear the user cant use the 2nd or 3rd multiplier .its like the user enter a resistor value and when he press the button the 1st time it multplies it by 1000 so it becomes Kohms and when he press again it will be Mohms.

Comment: so what code should I write so that when the button is pressed the user can press done without setting it to the value he entered and not affecting the text should return method ?  
@DrummerB